# serializer.is_valid() crashes, 500 internal server error

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm making a django-rest-framework API for post, inheriting APIView. I'm using a serializer, that inherits djangos ModelSerializer. In the beginning of post, I try to validate the post, for example:

```
serializer = ExampleSerializerPOST(data=request.DATA)
if not serializer.is_valid():
    return Response(serializer.errors, 400)
```

I tried to test the post without sending any data with it. I expected that it would return 400 because serializer was not valid. But instead, I get 500, internal server error? Why? I have inspected it, and it crashes in the serializer.is_valid(). There is something I clearly do not understand. In what circumstances does the is_valid() crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved. It was due to a syntax error in the serializer. Apparently, when you define a serializer that inherits a ModelSerializer, you cannot put a single field with just field = 'message'. What I had was:

```
class ExampleSerializerPOST(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = 'message'
```

This caused the 500 internal error. What worked when dealing with just one field, was this:

```
class ExampleSerializerPOST(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('message',)
```

So lame I know. You do not only need the parenthesis, that comma is also required. This was confusing, since I did try without the comma couple times. This should have definately been mentioned in the Django rest framework's docs.

Comment: the comma is required in a Python tuple.